# Using an element from another schema as a nested element

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to write a schema (say, A.xsd) which uses elements from a second schema (say, B.xsd) written for a different project. The pre-existing schema (ie B.xsd) defines several top-level elements. For example:

Snippet from B.xsd:

```
<xs:element name="macAddress">
    <xs:complexType>
    ....
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, when I use these elements from B.xsd in A.xsd, they need to be inner nested elements of some other elements, and not top-level elements as they were in B.xsd. Thus, a simple "import" of the A.xsd namespace for the macAddress and other elements does not seem to work for me, since the import causes these elements to be top-level elements for A.xsd as well.

I then tried using the "abstract=true" attribute for the top-level elements in B.xsd, like so:

```
<xs:element name="macAddress" abstract="true">
<xs:complexType>
    ....
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and then wrote A.xsd as below:

```
<xs:import namespace="urn:xyz:BNamespace"
          schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\a\Documents\B.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="root">
<xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="BPrefix:macAddress"/> <!-- BPrefix is defined -->
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, this schema then generates a following error during validation:
"The QName {urn:xyz:BNamespace}macAddress does not resolve to a(n) element declaration."

I am unable to understand what this error means. Note that when the element  is defined within A.xsd itself, this error does not occur. However, several references on the web suggest that the "ref" attribute allows an external namespace prefix.

Can someone please point me to what the error is in my A.xsd schema? Or else suggest someway of achieving my original requirement, which is basically to write a schema which uses element definitions from another schema as nested inner elements?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an element must be globally defined in order to `@ref` it within a local definition, and this will then allow that globally defined element to appear as a possible alternative root element in the document.   This is true whether your XSD is defined over one or multiple files.

To have purely local elements, define global types instead and use `@type` to reference the shared, global type rather than `@ref` to reference a globally defined element.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes for the response. I did consider changing element definitions in B.xsd to global type definitions instead of element definitions. However, some of those element definitions need to have <key> child elements. It seems that a <complexType> cannot have key information within it, and I would ideally want all tags that describe these elements/types to be within B.xsd only, and only refer to them by name/type in A.xsd.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have declared the  `macAddress` element in `B.xsd` like the following::

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:xyz:BNamespace"> 

    <xs:element name="macAddress">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="X"/>
            </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You can use this element in another schema (A.xsd) as follow:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:BPrefix="urn:xyz:BNamespace"> 

    <xs:import namespace="urn:xyz:BNamespace"
        schemaLocation="file:///C:\Users\a\Documents\B.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="BPrefix:macAddress"/> <!-- BPrefix is defined -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Without the 'abstract=true' attribute on the 'macAddress' element definition in B.xsd, my schema will start allowing macAddress elements to be top-level elements as well as nested elements, which I don't want to allow. Hence I need to use abstract attrib.